# Checkbox doesn't work as expected after append with Jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, append

I append a checkbox with:

```
$('#lijst1').append('<tr id="tr' + responseJSON.up_id + '">' +
    '<td><input type="checkbox" name="row_arr[]" value="' + responseJSON.up_id + '" class="checkbox" />' + 
    '<td><a href="#" class="editButton1 ui-icon ui-icon-wrench" id="' + responseJSON.up_id + '" tooltip="" onclick="" ></a></td>' + 
    '</tr>');
```

If I check the checkbox and submit the form, the checkbox id isn't posted. Also if I check all checkboxes with a javascript script, the new added checkbox isn't checked.

PS: The new added checkbox is placed within the form tag.

Answer (score 0):

its because of security issues since beginning of html5, also if you wrap the form elements with `.wrap()` form contents won't submitted, try a different method, like:

```
var html = '<tr id="tr' + responseJSON.up_id + '">' +
    '<td><input type="checkbox" name="row_arr[]" value="' + responseJSON.up_id + '" class="checkbox" />' + 
    '<td><a href="#" class="editButton1 ui-icon ui-icon-wrench" id="' + responseJSON.up_id + '" tooltip="" onclick="" ></a></td>' + 
    '</tr>';


$('#lijst1').html( $('#lijst1').html() + html)
```

Comment: Mmm, if that's the case I have a problem. I don't know any different method besides first refreshing the page by the user.

Comment: @emeijer i had the same problem before, i was wondering why form data was not submitted, some jquery methods are problematic with the form elements.

Comment: I have solved it by reloading the page when script is ready. It's dirty but it works.